# select from table where field type is INT

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a trigger that runs `BEFORE INSERT` on `other table`

```sql
BEGIN
  DECLARE test VARCHAR(3000);
  SELECT APPLICATION.APP_DATA into @test FROM APPLICATION WHERE  APP_NUMBER=1 LIMIT 1;
END
```

Type of `APP_NUMBER` is `INT` and when the trigger runs `@test` is `NULL`. Why?

When I do

```sql
SELECT APPLICATION.APP_DATA 
  FROM APPLICATION 
 WHERE APP_NUMBER=1 LIMIT 1;`
```

it returns a correct value!

Comment: You better explain what are you trying to accomplish with your trigger

Comment: .. ok - so why not fix / change that and see if it makes any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off MySQL supports two **distinct** types of variables local and user (session) variables.

Now with `DECLARE` you define a local variable `test` but then trying to assign a value to a session variable `@test`.

It's absolutely unclear what and why you're trying to achieve but here is a working example

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE test VARCHAR(32);
  SELECT app_data INTO test FROM application WHERE app_number = 1 LIMIT 1;
  SET NEW.data = test;
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68309/1)** demo